# How do I run webm video file in firefox using HTML5 on linux?

Tags: linux, video, firefox, html

I am using apache server on linux and want to run a .webm video file. I have .webm video file which i am trying to run in firefox (V 12.0) using HTML5 but the browser is showing as "no video with supported format and MIME types found". I have added mime type in httpd.conf file. The video is running in chrome on windows machine which is a client machine. Please tell, if any configuration settings are required.

Comment: Umm, Firefox 12? Is there a reason you're using such an ancient version?

Answer (score 0):

Visit `https://www.youtube.com/html5?`

you will have something like:

[image]

1) Open the Firefox browser and type the following in the address bar:

```
about:config
```

A warning page may appear that says "This might void your warranty!". Click "I'll be careful, I promise!" to continue to the about:config page.

2) Type the word: `media.fragmented-mp4` in the filter text box.
There are 5 parameters disabled.Keep the last one false and double click on the 4 others to change its value to true.

3)Type `media.mediasource` in the filter text box and set all values to true.

Restart firfox and visit `https://www.youtube.com/html5?`

you will get something like:

[image]